# Create Tab Names from List - Google Sheets / Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like Tab names to be created and named from a list in Sheet 1

please see the 2 images below.

1.List of Job Numbers to be used

[image: Image 1]

2.tab names are now created and changed - see below
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Can I ask you about your goal? You want to create new sheets in the active Spreadsheet by giving the sheet name from the column "A" of a sheet? Or You want to rename the existing sheets in the active Spreadsheet by giving the sheet name from the column "A" of a sheet? By the way, can you provide your current issue of your script?

Comment: Tanaike - very sorry this is my 2nd question today that has been closed. it was answered by Marios. thank you for trying to solve my issue.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that I couldn't understand about your question by my poor English skill. But I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You get the values of Column **A** of **Sheet1**:

  ```
  const sh_names = sh1.getRange(1,1,sh1.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();
  ```
- You iterate over `sh_names` and **for each name** you create a sheet:

  ```
  sh_names.forEach(n=>ss.insertSheet(n));
  ```

---

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const sh_names = sh1.getRange(1,1,sh1.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();
  sh_names.forEach(n=>ss.insertSheet(n));
}
```

---

### References:

- [insertSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertsheet)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)